# Pure Python Web App Framework compatible with 2.4.3

Tags: python, web-frameworks

My host only has python 2.4.3 and I don't have shell access. What choices do I have for a pure python-based web app framework?

edit: I should also probably say it's running as CGI on the server.

Comment: Long term I probably will if they don't upgrade to 2.7 but for now I've a few small projects to be getting on with

Answer (score 3):

You should get a new host, seriously. That version of Python is *ancient*.

If you must insist, though, you could try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It is my favorite platform, if that will sway your opinion.

Comment: does it require shell access to install?

Comment: What to you mean by that? You can't SSH in? I doubt that any Python framework will do that, then, as Flask needs to open ports.

Comment: yes I can't SSH in. This is why I would like if at all possible a 'pure python' solution that doesn't require building into the http server. Maybe that's impossible mind you.

Comment: Python has CGI support built-in. You can try working with it: http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts

Comment: actually was just browsing that page as you posted that. If that's the only way to do it then I'll just have to jump hosts faster than I had planned.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)?

Comment: I don't have shell access - can I install django without it?